# How to use getUpdates() with JSON

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telepot

I found a method online that I am using for retrieving messages and updating bot.

Here is the code I found:

```py
def getMessage(self, offset):
    if offset:
        update = self.bot.getUpdates(offset=offset) 
    else:
        update = self.bot.getUpdates()
    update_json = json.loads(update[2])
    return update_json
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '  
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Update
```

I want to return the message as a json, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using `telepot` library.

Regarding this error:

> TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
>   TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Update

Function `json.loads()` receives a `str` and returns a `dict`. [As long as](https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#receive-messages) `update` is a `list` of `Update`s, `update[2]` is an `Update`. And you're passing `update[2]` to `json.loads()`, hence the error above.

---

> I want to return the message as a json

I don't understand what do you mean by "returning a JSON", but here's 2 options described in comments. Choose the right `return` for you:

```py
def getMessage(self, offset):
    if offset:
        updates = self.bot.getUpdates(offset=offset) 
    else:
        updates = self.bot.getUpdates()

    # updates is a list of <Update> objects
    # an <Update> can or can not be a <Message>

    # if you want to return a message from a third update as a python dict use this:
    return updates[2]["message"]  # dict

    ### OR ###

    # if you want to return a message from a third update as a JSON string, use this:
    return json.dumps(update[2]["message"])  # JSON string
```

#### Side note

I also don't understand why are you trying to return the third element from updates list.

Just be aware that `updates` can be an empty list (or list with less than 3 elements in it) and `updates[2]` will raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: No problem) just try the example

Comment: Ok, sorry python is not my first language... so what i am trying to run is [link]github.com/woj-ciech/Social-media-c2/blob/master/social.py [link]medium.com/@woj_ciech/… I just can not get it running! –